# Unable to append data to csv in R

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, dataframe

I'm reading a csv file and calculating columns and appending result to a csv , but Im unable to do it
here is the code

```
ahg = list()
for(i in 1:3){
  ahg[[i]] = " X+Y" #calculating columns
  print(ahg[[i]])
  write.csv(ahg[[i]],"D:/wed.csv")
}
```

O\P of `print(ahg[[i]])` gives

```
[1] 20
[1] 13.51
[1] 15.25
```

But the O\P of write.csv i.e `wed.csv` gives only last value i.e `15.25` 
Any suggestion what Im doing wrong

Thanks.

Comment: `write.csv(..., append=TRUE)`.  But you can probably write the whole list in a single pass, you shouldn't have to loop over it.

Comment: No, didnt worked, instead gave warning "Warning messages:
1: In write.csv(ahg[[i]], "D:/wed.csv", append = TRUE) :
  attempt to set 'append' ignored"

Comment: That's because on your first iteration append won't do anything if the file doesn't already exist.  Please read `?write.csv`

Comment: Yes writing the whole list in a single pass append data in column wise and not row wise

Answer (score 1):

You can't write an extra value at the end of each line of the file. That is not how `write.csv()` works.

You will need to

- read in the table (or other structure)
- create the new calculated column (or other value)
- re-write the new version (use the default `append = FALSE`).

For example:

```
# create example CSV
data(iris)
write.csv(iris, 'test.csv', row.names=FALSE)

# ------- this is what you need to do --------
df <- read.csv('test.csv')

# create a new column
df$Petal.Area <- df$Petal.Length * df$Petal.Width

# over-write the file, but make sure you have a backup somewhere
write.csv(df, 'test.csv', row.names=FALSE)

# --- end of example -- you can delete it now ---
file.remove('test.csv')
```

Comment: solved the problem by using these lines outside for loop "q=do.call("rbind", ahg)
dist=as.data.frame(q)

write.csv(ahg,"D:/wed.csv",append=F)"